# JavaScript TypeError for declared function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class="test" id="chk" /><label for="chk">Click</label>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

JavaScript

```
(function (){
 var chk = document.querySelector('.test');

 function ClickTest(elem){
    this.elem = elem;
 };

ClickTest.prototype.addListener = function() {
   this.elem.addEventListener('change', this.showValue);
};
ClickTest.prototype.showValue = function(){
   console.log('Clicked');
   var d = document.getElementById('demo');
   d.innerHTML = "This works";
   this.test();
};
ClickTest.prototype.test = function(){
   console.log('Test function');
};

clickTest = new ClickTest(chk);
clickTest.addListener();
})();
```

My code works fine before `this.test()` is called. The error I get is

> TypeError: this.test is not a function

Is it because `showValue` is called from `addEventListener` or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the addEventListener is invoking the method, it's context is being changed to that of the addEventListener function ( you can console log `this` on the `showValue` to test ). This can be fixed (every pun intended) using the `bind` method:

```
ClickTest.prototype.addListener = function() {
   this.elem.addEventListener('change', this.showValue.bind(this) );
};
```

This ensures that the context is maintained. What `bind` does is essentially forces the method to be called in the scope of what it has been bound to. In our case, we are binding it to `ClickTest` by passing in `this`.